# Laravel Eloquent ORM можно ли сохранять через связи

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Допустим у меня есть две модели: `User` и `Friend`

И простое связывание один к одному:

```
public function friend() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Friend');
}
```

Связывание таблиц по user_id упустим (и так понятно что оно есть)...

Суть вопроса: Правильно ли, искать нужный объект модели, через хелпер, затем через связывание и затем сохранять без прямого поиска по таблице?

Пример:

```
 $user = auth()->user();
 $friend = $user->friend;
 $friend->column = 'changevalue';
 $friend->save();
```

Никаких ошибок при таком использовании нет, всё работает как и задумывалось, но правильно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это нормальная практика.

Вот документация - **https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method**

К тому же связи и созданы во избежания прямого поиска по таблице.
Зачем делать лишний findOrFail, если через связь сделается тот же запрос, только красивее и лаконичнее.